# Integral too slow and with conditionals

Tags: integral-equations

When I try to solve this integral:
$$\int_{-a}^a \frac{x}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{3/2}} \, dy$$

it's return

```
ConditionalExpression[(2 a)/(x Sqrt[a^2 + x^2]), 
  Im[x]^2 <= 
    Re[x]^2 && (Im[x/a] > 1 || Im[x/a] < -1 || 
     Re[x/a] != 
      0) && (Sqrt[-((Im[x] Re[x])/(Im[a] Re[a]))] ∉ 
      Reals || 
     Im[x] (Im[x] + (Re[a] Re[x])/Im[a]) <= 
      Re[x] ((Im[a] Im[x])/Re[a] + Re[x]) || 
     Re[Sqrt[-((Im[x] Re[x])/(Im[a] Re[a]))]] >= 1)]
```

and takes *37s* to solve!

Is there any particular reason?
Is there a way to obtain only the `[[1]]` part ?

Comment: use assumptions `Integrate[x/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2), {y, -a, a}, 
 Assumptions -> (x | y) \[Element] Reals && x > 0 && a > 0]`.  This is likely a duplicate, but I can't find which one.

Comment: I get it now!Now how can i do this automatic with something like $Pre ...

Comment: you can do `$Assumptions = {(x | y) \[Element] Reals && x > 0 && a > 0}` instead of giving the option to `Integrate`  (be aware though that only functions that take an assumptions argument actually use the `$Assumptions` variable.. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can throw your assumptions into `Assuming` as follows:

```
Assuming[{y ∈ Reals, x > 0, a > 0}, Integrate[x/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2), {y, -a, a}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is good to find the general integration and then find the bounded one using substitution.

```
int[y_] = Integrate[x/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2), y];
int[a] - int[-a]

(*(2 a)/(x Sqrt[a^2 + x^2])*)
```